# How do you suppress environment variable expansion within DOS and Windows CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, dos

This is a simplified example with modified variable names of what I want to do.  Also for simplicity sake, I am showing the command line version rather than the bat file version.

I am doing the following.

```
> echo %foo%

%foo%
```

However, if foo is a valid environment variable, I do not get desired output (`%foo%`) due to environment variable expansion.

```
> set foo=bar
> echo %foo%
> echo %%foo%%

bar
%bar%
```

Now, I have a hack to do (following example) this but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to either output a `%` character or to suppress environment variable expansion.

```
> set foo=bar
> set percent=%
> echo %percent%foo%percent%

%foo%
```

Also, if the required solution is different in a bat file (like `%%` rather than `%` or `%1%` rather than `%1`) please let me know.

My actual use case is in a bat file with `SETX` to set global environment variables that rely on another environment variable to be expanded within them but I'm curious as to how to expand in either DOS or cmd.

Comment: Can you explain "that rely on another environment variable to be expanded within them."  Do you want some nested expansion but not others in the same parseable string?

Comment: @cdkMoose:  I want to set a global env. var to be something like `FOO_SDK_BIN=%FOO_SDK%/BIN` but not expand `%FOO_SDK%` with SETX.  Then if I change the FOO_SDK variable path with SETX, all variables that rely on it will be properly repathed as well.  It's just to make a script to simplify setup of a bunch of development machines where we use a 3rd party SDK that has quite a few env variables like this that can all be rooted to a single env var.

Comment: I'm not familair with SETX, but it sounds like you are sying you don't want it to expand with SETX "I want to set a global env. var to be something like FOO_SDK_BIN=%FOO_SDK%/BIN but not expand %FOO_SDK% with SETX."  But then you later want it to expand after you have changed the value behind the variable using SETX.  In any one statement, it either will or will not expand but not both.

Comment: SETX can set global env variables (that are visible in other command prompts and apps) - the ones stored in HKCU and HKLM (using /M) in the registry.  It has been around since VISTA as part of OS and was part of supplemental tools for XP.  Basically these are the variables stored under "Advanced System Settings" Control Panel on the "Advanced" Tab under the "Environment Variables" Button.

Comment: note that `setx` is not a DOS command. [DOS and cmd.exe are not the same thing](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in a batch file, echo %%foo%% will generate %foo%.

```
c:\01Temp>type foo.bat
@echo %%foo%%

c:\01Temp>foo
%foo%

c:\01Temp>
```

Comment: D'Oh! I was thrown off because that doesn't work on the command line if foo is set (%%foo%% expands to %bar% on command line). Is there a way other than the hack (set percent=%) to do it on the command line ?

Answer (score 2):

Within a batch file, use two `%%`s, e.g.:

```
set foo=1
echo %%foo%%
```

...echoes "%foo%", not "1". I'm not aware of a way to disable it in immediate mode (e.g., not in a batch file).

Comment: Yeah, I was thrown off because it wasn't working the way I wanted in immediate mode no matter how many %'s I had in a row.