# Is there a way to prevent percent expansion of env variable in Windows command line?

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, variable-expansion

I'm using the following git command in git bash on Windows:

```
git log --format="%C(cyan)%cd%Creset %s" --date=short -5
```

It displays commit date (`%cd`) followed by commit message (`%s`). Commit date is wrapped with color markers: `%C(cyan)` to start colored output and `%Creset` to stop colored output.

While it works fine in git bash, it doesn't do well with `cmd`: `%cd%` is expanded by Windows shell into current working directory (equivalent of `$PWD` in bash).

**Hence when that command is run via `cmd`, I see current working directory displayed instead of commit date in the first column!**
git bash:

```
2015-10-08 commit msg
2015-10-08 commit msg
2015-10-07 commit msg
2015-10-06 commit msg
2015-10-06 commit msg
```

cmd:

```
D:\git\someFolderCreset commit msg
D:\git\someFolderCreset commit msg
D:\git\someFolderCreset commit msg
D:\git\someFolderCreset commit msg
D:\git\someFolderCreset commit msg
```

Actually, I never use `cmd` directly myself, I found this behavior while writing a nodejs (0.12) script in which I had

```
require('child_process').execSync('git log --format=...', {stdio: 'inherit'})
```

which gets executed by node using the `cmd` when on Windows).

A simple workaround could be to introduce a space to prevent `%cd%` being found, i.e. change

```
git log --format="%C(cyan)%cd%Creset %s" --date=short -5
```

to

```
git log --format="%C(cyan)%cd %Creset%s" --date=short -5
```

However this introduced a redundant space (I deleted another space before `%s` but it's still a hack, and requires manual intervention).

Is there a way to prevent expansion by the Windows shell?

I've [found](https://superuser.com/questions/78214/how-can-i-stop-percentage-expansion-in-a-batch-file) information about using `%%` or `^%` to escape the `%` but they are not the solution here:

```
# produces superfluous ^ characters
git log --format="%C(cyan)^%cd^%Creset %s" --date=short -5

^2015-10-08^ commit msg
^2015-10-08^ commit msg
^2015-10-07^ commit msg
^2015-10-06^ commit msg
^2015-10-06^ commit msg

# seems the expansion is done at command parse time
git log --format="%C(cyan)%%cd%%Creset %s" --date=short -5

%D:\git\someFolder commit msg
%D:\git\someFolder commit msg
%D:\git\someFolder commit msg
%D:\git\someFolder commit msg
%D:\git\someFolder commit msg
```

The ideal solution should be either compatible with bash and cmd, without producing redundant characters, or an escape function in javascript to escape the generic UNIX-y command for Windows to prevent the expansions (if such an escape function can be created).

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058944/how-do-you-suppress-environment-variable-expansion-within-dos) `%%` works in BAT files but not in the command line

Comment: `ECHO git log --format=^"^%C^(cyan^)^%cd^%Creset ^%s^" --date=short -5` Escaped all `CMD` _poisonous_ characters for `ECHO` command.

Comment: @JosefZ: That works great on Windows, but not on Unix-like systems, where the `^` chars. are retained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To provide an alternative to [MC ND's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023221/45375):

**If you really *need* to get the *shell* involved** (which is unlikely, because you state that you want the command to work both with Windows' `cmd.exe` *and* Bash), consider the solution immediately below; for a ***shell-less* alternative that *bypasses* the problem**, see the solution at the **bottom**.

<sup>Tip of the hat to [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) for improving my original approach by suggesting placing double-quotes around `%` instances rather than the potential variable names *between* `%` instances, and for suggesting a clarification re `execFileSync`.</sup>

---

#### "Escaping" `%` chars. for `cmd.exe`

As stated in [MC ND's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023221/45375), you cannot technically escape `%` at the Windows command prompt (inside batch files you can use `%%`, but that doesn't work when invoking shell commands from other environments such as Node.js, and generally wouldn't work across platforms).

However, the **workaround** is to **place double-quotes around each `%` instance**:

```
// Input shell command.
var shellCmd = 'git log --format="%C(cyan)%cd%Creset %s" --date=short -5'

// Place a double-quote on either end of each '%'
// This yields (not pretty, but it works):
//   git log --format=""%"C(cyan)"%"cd"%"Creset "%"s" --date=short -5
var escapedShellCmd = shellCmd.replace(/%/g, '"%"')

// Should work on both Windows and Unix-like platforms:
console.log(require('child_process').execSync(escapedShellCmd).toString())
```

The inserted double-quotes prevent `cmd.exe` from recognizing tokens such as `%cd%` as variable references (`"%"cd"%"` won't get expanded).

This works, because the extra double-quotes are ultimately stripped from the string when processed by the target program:

- **Windows**: `git.exe` (presumably via the C runtime) then takes care of stripping the extra double-quotes from the combined string.
- **Unix-like** (POSIX-like shells such as Bash): the shell itself takes care of removing the double-quotes before passing them to the target program.

  - *Caveat*: Using *double-quotes* in your command in general means that you need to watch out for POSIX-like shells performing potentially unwanted expansions on `$`-prefixed tokens (not an issue here); however, in order to remain Windows-compatible you *must* use double-quotes.

<sup>Technically, applying this technique to a double-quoted string breaks it into a sequence of double-quoted *substrings* interspersed with *unquoted* `%` instances. POSIX-like shells still recognize this as a *single* string - the substrings are double-quoted and directly abut the `%` instances. (If you apply the technique to an *unquoted* string, the logic is reversed: you're effectively splicing in double-quoted `%` instances.) The double-quotes around the substrings, which are considered syntactical elements rather than part of the string, are then removed when the substrings are joined together to form the single literal to pass to the target program.</sup>

---

#### Bypassing the problem by avoiding the shell altogether

**Note**: The following builds on `execFile[Sync]`, which only works for **calling *external executables*** (which is true in the OP's case: `git.exe`) - by contrast, for calling *shell builtins* (internal commands) or Windows *batch files*, you cannot avoid `exec[Sync]` and thus interpretation by `cmd.exe` (on Windows).<sup>[1]</sup>

If you **use [`execFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfilesync_file_args_options)** rather than `execSync`, the **shell (`cmd.exe` on Windows) will NOT be involved** and thus you **needn't worry about escaping `%` chars.** or any other shell metacharacters, for that matter:

```
require('child_process').execFileSync('git', 
   [ 'log', 
     '--format=%C(cyan)%cd%Creset %s',
     '--date=short',
     '-5' ], {stdio: 'inherit'})
```

Note how the arguments must be supplied *individually* as elements of an *array*, and *without embedded quoting*.

---

<sup>[1] On Windows, script files (e.g., Python scripts) cannot be called directly with `execFile[Sync]`, but you can instead pass the interpreter executable (e.g., `python`) as the file to execute, and the script file as an argument. On Unix-like platforms you *can* call scripts directly, as long as they have a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and are marked as executable.

`execFile[Sync]` *can* be used to invoke Windows *batch files*, but `cmd.exe` invariably interpolates the arguments, as with `exec[Sync]`.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

In short, <del>you can not do it or at least there is not a general method</del>

**note** I was wrong. [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33026344/2861476) pointed a way for a general solution.

Of course, you can use `^`, not to escape the percent signs (you can not escape the percent signs at command line level) but to separate the percent sign from the name of the variable so it is not detected as a variable to be expanded. That is, for your case, it is enough to use

```
git log --format="%C(cyan)%cd^%Creset %s" --date=short -5
```

but as you point the caret is not consumed by the parser and is included in the output string.

So, any *"escape"* characters will be included in the output both in `cmd` and `bash`, but it can be solved for this particular (or similar) case using

```
process.env.cd = '%cd%'
require('child_process').execSync(
    'git log --format="%C(cyan)%cd%Creset %s" --date=short -5'
    , {stdio: 'inherit'}
)
```

Basically, what the code does is assign a fake value to the `cd` environment variable, changing it to the literal `%cd%`, so, when the `cmd` parser executes the variable expansion, the correct value ends in the command line.

But, maybe (I have not checked how/what the `git` code does) changing the `cd` variable could interfere. So, also for this case, instead of changing the value of the `cd` variable you can use

```
process.env['C(cyan)'] = '%C(cyan)%';
```

Why? When the `cmd` parser processes the command line, it will match the start of the format string against the existing variable, do the expansion and in the same process consume the starting percent sign in the `%cd%` variable, so it is not expanded.