# How to Echo a variable without calling it?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that creates another batch file (Compile.bat) and need to echo the %errorlevel% variable into Compile.bat, but since it's a global variable when it is called is uses current value.

This is the code

```
ECHO if NOT "%errorlevel%"=="0" PAUSE >> .\%name%\Compile.bat
```

But Compile.bat receives

```
if NOT "0"=="0" PAUSE
```

Is there a way to stop it from thinking %errorlevel% is a variable?

Comment: The outer brackets for your comparisons are not needed.  You can just use double quotes. `ECHO if NOT "%%errorlevel%%"=="0" PAUSE >> .\%name%\Compile.bat`

Comment: [Is there a way to prevent percent expansion of env variable in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33016094/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the errorlevel variable with double `%%` like this:

```
ECHO if NOT "%%errorlevel%%"=="0" PAUSE >> .\%name%\Compile.bat
```

I think this is what you wanted:

```
if NOT "%errorlevel%"=="0" PAUSE
```

Comment: Your explanation is not generic enough.  The issue is the percent symbols.  Not the variable.  If you need to echo a percent symbol to another file you always double the percent symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some helper code for you.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "name=SomeName"
Set "variable=Value"
Rem Write to Compile.bat
Echo Press any key to write to Compile.bat
Pause > Nul
(
    Echo @Echo Off
    Echo %%variable%% = %variable%
    Echo Pause
) > "%name%\Compile.bat"
Echo Finished writing to Compile.bat
Timeout 3 /NoBreak > Nul
Rem Rest of code below here
```