# Issue with using PowerShell command in batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, escaping

I download a zip file from my cloud using a PowerShell command.
The command works correctly in PowerShell AND in the command line. However, if I insert the command from the command line into my batch script, only the html is downloaded.
Why does the command work correctly in the command line but not in the batch file?
Im out of ideas :D

```
powershell Invoke-WebRequest """https://sync.luckycloud.de/d/fb56e4a8239a4c6cac7a/files/?p=%2FValheimServer%20Buddelkiste%20Modpack%20v3.4%20-%20Standart.zip&dl=1""" -OutFile """C:\Users\Anonymos\Downloads\servermodpack.zip"""
```

Its works complete fine in cmd and load the ~40 Mb. But in Batch it loads only 9kb (its the Html)

Comment: If this PowerShell code is part of a larger batch file I would suggest you use `CURL` to download the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In a *batch file*** - as opposed to the *interactive* `cmd.exe` command prompt<sup>[1]</sup> - **you need to to *escape* `%` chars. as `%%` in order to pass them through literally**:

```
powershell -c "Invoke-WebRequest 'https://sync.luckycloud.de/d/fb56e4a8239a4c6cac7a/files/?p=%%2FValheimServer%%20Buddelkiste%%20Modpack%%20v3.4%%20-%%20Standart.zip&dl=1' -OutFile C:\Users\Anonymos\Downloads\servermodpack.zip"
```

Note:

- I've used `-c` (`-Command`), the *positionally* implied *Windows PowerShell* CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)) parameter explicitly for conceptual clarity (in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, whose CLI is [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the default is now `-f` (`-File`)).
- Also, enclosing *the entire command line* to pass to PowerShell in `"..."` is generally preferable in order to prevent `cmd.exe` metacharacters *other* than `%` (such as `&`) from causing problems.

  - In case the command line requires use of *embedded* `"` characters (the solution above avoids this by using embedded `'...'` quoting), the safest way to escape them is to use `"^""` (sic) with `powershell.exe`, and `""` with `pwsh.exe` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for details.

---

<sup>[1] In interactive use, `%` characters cannot technically be *escaped*, but they're retained as-is *unless they're part of a `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable reference* that refers to an *existing* environment variable, such as `%OS%`. However, there are ways to treat `%` literally even in such cases, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33026344/45375). These techniques are important for invoking `cmd.exe` command lines *programmatically* from *outside* `cmd.exe`, such as from Node.Js or Python, because such programmatic invocations - perhaps surprisingly - use the rules of *interactive* `cmd.exe` sessions, not batch files.</sup>