# Passing arguments to a python program

Tags: python, windows, shell, command-line-arguments, argv

I have a python program that receives a file path as an argument.

The problem is, that if the file path has the following chars: "%cd", then it replaces "%cd" with the current directory.

So for example:

```
python program.py  "C:\%af%32%cd%7f.htm"
```

The sys.argv (in program.py) shows this:

```
['program.py', 'C:\\%af%32C:\\%7f.htm']
```

Why is that happening and how can it be solved?

**Edit**

The problem is that if I put "%cd" in the command line, then in python I get the command line with the current directory string instead the "%cd" chars

Comment: This is not a python issue, but a Windows CMD one. Windows CMD replaces %cd% before passing it to python.

Comment: @Ben Maybe.. In the mean time I didn't find that "%cd" works in windows CMD.. But I found that "%cd" is a special command in ipython

Comment: On Unix-like systems you stop parameter expansions like that by quoting the arg with single quotes (not double quotes). Doesn't that work on Windows?

Comment: Use %% in the command line see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058944/how-do-you-suppress-environment-variable-expansion-within-dos#2058972

Comment: @MartinBeckett Adding another % before each "%" character didn't work :(

Comment: #Drxxd - yes sorry that only works inside .bat scripts. See my answer below. From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016094/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-percent-expansion-of-env-variable-in-windows-command-l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping % with %% only works within batch files, not on the commandline.
It is possible to escape % with double quote

eg:
`python untitled0.py "C:\\"%"af"%"32"%"cd"%"7f.htm"`

`['untitled0.py', 'C:\"%af%32%cd%7f.htm']`

But this is a bit tedious - and you have to be careful of `\` escaping any of the `"`.

Another alternative would be to replace % with some other symbol and then change it back inside the python program?

Comment: You forgot to remove the double quote from the output.

Comment: Note that handling the quotes on the command line is a two-part process. First, quoting prevents CMD from interpreting special characters (e.g. "&"), but CMD passes the quotes on the command line exactly as written. It's up to the child process to remove them, which is usually via the C runtime, which parses the command line into the `argv` list. [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391) follows similar rules.

Comment: @eryksun it looks like the python interpreter strips them. That was the output of just  print(sys.argv) in python

Comment: Yes, Python gets `argv` from the C runtime, but I wanted to clarify the role of the shell here for Unix users who might assume the shell handles removing the quotes and creating an `argv` array. Windows programs get a command line string, and it's up to each program how it should be parsed.